# Spark createDataframe from RDD of objects, column order

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to convert an RDD of my custom objects (a Java class) to a Dataframe, I simply used the method hiveContext.createDataframe specifying the class of the object. The problem is that the dataframe is created with columns in some strange order, and once I write the DF to Hive the values are in the wrong columns.
Here is my code:

`var objectRDD = tableDF.map((r: Row) => new Attuatore(r(0),r(1)...))
 [.. operations with the RDD ..]
 val resultDF = hiveContext.createDataFrame(objectRDD, classOf[Attuatore])
 resultDF.write.mode("append").saveAsTable(outputTable)`

The only solution I found so far for having the fields in the right order is to convert back the RDD[Attuatore] to an RDD[Row], and then call createDataFrame() specifying the schema, but since I have to do this with a lot of classes I would prefer the first approach to have a much cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation for HiveContext.createDataFrame says

> Since there is no guaranteed ordering for fields in a Java Bean, 
>   SELECT * queries will return the columns in an undefined order.

So if you need to put fields in a defined order, you have to do it explicitly, e.g.

```
val MY_COLUMNS = Seq("field1", "field2", ...)
val conformedDF = resultDF.select(MY_COLUMNS.map(col(_)):_*)
conformedDF.write...
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, it says expected Seq[Column] found Seq[Any], but I think that just using val conformedDF = resultDF.select("field1", "field2", ...) will work

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, since fixed. My expectation was that you'd be getting the list of columns (in desired order) from somewhere else (reflection, metadata, etc.), rather than hardcoding them inline. Obviously the latter is simpler, if you're okay with that.

Comment: I'm getting the cols from the Java class, do you know how to convert an Array[String] in order to pass it to the select method? At the mom. I'm using (cols.head,cols.tail:_*) where cols is the array (I don't know Scala)

Comment: You can use the toSeq method on Array, e.g. `def conform(df: DataFrame, columns: Array[String]): DataFrame = { df.select(columns.toSeq.map(col(_)):_*) }`

but the head,tail overload works as well, as long as you always have at least one column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation